# places to look for code to convert a data file to X12 format?

Tags: python, x12

I have a data file that looks similar to:

```
data1~|~data2~|~data3~!~data1~|~data2~|~data3~!~data1~|~data2~|~data3~!~data1~|~data2~|~data3~!~
```

The fields are delimited by `~|~` (tilde/pipe/tilde). The row/records are delimited by `~!~`.

The goal will be to massage this into an X12 formatted file. I will have many files and many records.. thousands of each.. I just started the project so I am exploring solutions.

I have done a little bit of coding in python so maybe that would work but not sure.

I am looking for suggestions or a library that may contain something to look at at to get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = "data1~|~data2~|~data3~!~data1~|~data2~|~data3~!~data1~|~data2~|~data3~!~data1~|~data2~|~data3~!~"

## parse rows
rows = data.split("~!~")

## Parse Columns 
final = [x.split("~|~") for x in rows]
print(final)
```

result is:

```
[['data1', 'data2', 'data3'], ['data1', 'data2', 'data3'], ['data1', 'data2', 'data3'], ['data1', 'data2', 'data3'], ['']]
```

The next step would be converting to XML.

Then once you have it converted to XML, use:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyx12/2.1.1 to convert it to X12

Then like magic, you should be done!

Comment: thank you. i appreciate the input. after scouring the net i came to the conclusion it would probably be a 2 step process.

Comment: I count 3 steps above:  Convert to Python native format, convert to xml, convert xml to x12.  EIther way, if you are done with this question, mark it as correct please :D